# Error deploying war to jboss eap through Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jboss

I am facing an issue while deploying war to jboss eap through Jenkins using deploy to container plugin:

```
[DeployPublisher][INFO] Attempting to deploy 1 war file(s)
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to create deployer with implementation class org.codehaus.cargo.container.jboss.JBoss51xRemoteDeployer for the parameters (container [id = [jboss6x]], deployer type [remote]).
    at org.codehaus.cargo.generic.spi.AbstractGenericHintFactory.createImplementation(AbstractGenericHintFactory.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.generic.spi.AbstractIntrospectionGenericHintFactory.createImplementation(AbstractIntrospectionGenericHintFactory.java:89)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.generic.deployer.DefaultDeployerFactory.createDeployer(DefaultDeployerFactory.java:131)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.generic.deployer.DefaultDeployerFactory.createDeployer(DefaultDeployerFactory.java:150)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:69)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:167)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:136)
    at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:3052)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:212)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:369)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Suppressed: hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to Slave1
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1743)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest$ExceptionResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:357)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:957)
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1072)
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1061)
        at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeployFile(CargoContainerAdapter.java:133)
        at hudson.plugins.deploy.PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.redeployFile(PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.java:95)
        at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:113)
        at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:79)
        at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:741)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
        at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1074)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
        at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1843)
        at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.generic.deployer.DefaultDeployerFactory.createInstance(DefaultDeployerFactory.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.generic.deployer.DefaultDeployerFactory.createInstance(DefaultDeployerFactory.java:40)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.generic.spi.AbstractGenericHintFactory.createImplementation(AbstractGenericHintFactory.java:148)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.cargo.util.CargoException: Cannot locate the JBoss connector classes! Make sure the required JBoss JARs (or Maven dependencies) are in CARGO's classpath.
More information on: https://codehaus-cargo.github.io/cargo/JBoss+Remote+Deployer.html
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.jboss.JBoss5xRemoteDeployer.<init>(JBoss5xRemoteDeployer.java:159)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.jboss.JBoss51xRemoteDeployer.<init>(JBoss51xRemoteDeployer.java:39)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1373)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1326)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1079)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteClassLoader$ClassLoaderProxy.fetch4(RemoteClassLoader.java:846)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteClassLoader$ClassLoaderProxy.fetch3(RemoteClassLoader.java:889)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor196.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$RPCRequest.perform(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:929)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:369)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.CallableDecorator.call(CallableDecorator.java:19)
    at hudson.remoting.CallableDecoratorList$1.call(CallableDecoratorList.java:21)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$2.call(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:46)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$2.call(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:71)
    ... 4 more
    Suppressed: hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to channel
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1743)
        at hudson.remoting.Request.call(Request.java:202)
        at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:286)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.fetch3(Unknown Source)
        at hudson.remoting.RemoteClassLoader.findClass(RemoteClassLoader.java:209)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.container.jboss.JBoss5xRemoteDeployer.<init>(JBoss5xRemoteDeployer.java:154)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.container.jboss.JBoss51xRemoteDeployer.<init>(JBoss51xRemoteDeployer.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.generic.deployer.DefaultDeployerFactory.createInstance(DefaultDeployerFactory.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.generic.deployer.DefaultDeployerFactory.createInstance(DefaultDeployerFactory.java:40)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.generic.spi.AbstractGenericHintFactory.createImplementation(AbstractGenericHintFactory.java:148)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.generic.spi.AbstractIntrospectionGenericHintFactory.createImplementation(AbstractIntrospectionGenericHintFactory.java:89)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.generic.deployer.DefaultDeployerFactory.createDeployer(DefaultDeployerFactory.java:131)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.generic.deployer.DefaultDeployerFactory.createDeployer(DefaultDeployerFactory.java:150)
        at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:69)
        at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:167)
        at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:136)
        at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:3052)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:212)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
        at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:369)
        at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
        ... 4 more
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.generic.deployer.DefaultDeployerFactory.createInstance(DefaultDeployerFactory.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.generic.deployer.DefaultDeployerFactory.createInstance(DefaultDeployerFactory.java:40)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.generic.spi.AbstractGenericHintFactory.createImplementation(AbstractGenericHintFactory.java:148)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.generic.spi.AbstractIntrospectionGenericHintFactory.createImplementation(AbstractIntrospectionGenericHintFactory.java:89)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.generic.deployer.DefaultDeployerFactory.createDeployer(DefaultDeployerFactory.java:131)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.generic.deployer.DefaultDeployerFactory.createDeployer(DefaultDeployerFactory.java:150)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:69)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:167)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:136)
    at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:3052)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:212)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:369)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.codehaus.cargo.util.CargoException: Cannot locate the JBoss connector classes! Make sure the required JBoss JARs (or Maven dependencies) are in CARGO's classpath.
More information on: https://codehaus-cargo.github.io/cargo/JBoss+Remote+Deployer.html
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.jboss.JBoss5xRemoteDeployer.<init>(JBoss5xRemoteDeployer.java:159)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.jboss.JBoss51xRemoteDeployer.<init>(JBoss51xRemoteDeployer.java:39)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1373)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1326)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1079)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteClassLoader$ClassLoaderProxy.fetch4(RemoteClassLoader.java:846)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteClassLoader$ClassLoaderProxy.fetch3(RemoteClassLoader.java:889)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor196.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$RPCRequest.perform(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:929)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:369)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.CallableDecorator.call(CallableDecorator.java:19)
    at hudson.remoting.CallableDecoratorList$1.call(CallableDecoratorList.java:21)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$2.call(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:46)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$2.call(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:71)
    ... 4 more
    Suppressed: hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to channel
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1743)
        at hudson.remoting.Request.call(Request.java:202)
        at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:286)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.fetch3(Unknown Source)
        at hudson.remoting.RemoteClassLoader.findClass(RemoteClassLoader.java:209)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.container.jboss.JBoss5xRemoteDeployer.<init>(JBoss5xRemoteDeployer.java:154)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.container.jboss.JBoss51xRemoteDeployer.<init>(JBoss51xRemoteDeployer.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.generic.deployer.DefaultDeployerFactory.createInstance(DefaultDeployerFactory.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.generic.deployer.DefaultDeployerFactory.createInstance(DefaultDeployerFactory.java:40)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.generic.spi.AbstractGenericHintFactory.createImplementation(AbstractGenericHintFactory.java:148)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.generic.spi.AbstractIntrospectionGenericHintFactory.createImplementation(AbstractIntrospectionGenericHintFactory.java:89)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.generic.deployer.DefaultDeployerFactory.createDeployer(DefaultDeployerFactory.java:131)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.generic.deployer.DefaultDeployerFactory.createDeployer(DefaultDeployerFactory.java:150)
        at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:69)
        at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:167)
        at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:136)
        at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:3052)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:212)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
        at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:369)
        at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
        ... 4 more
Build step 'Deploy war/ear to a container' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: A relevant part of the stacktrace seems to be `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory` .

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing some plugin configuration in your pom.xml can you cross check with https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/